# Port forwarding only works for one port to one device, but does not work if I put multiple ports on one device?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a list of ports that I want to forward to only one device. It works if I add *only* one port, but if I add many ports on one device, only one of the added ports will work. How do I fix it? Am I only limited to one port each device?

Comment: What you can and cannot do here will depend largely on the equipment you are using and the capabilities it has. I routinely forward multiple ports to multiple devices as well as ranges ( x thru xxx) of ports. You haven't told us what equipment you are trying to setup.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This question is hard to answer, as there are a lot of important details missing. Try to put yourself in the shoes of those who know nothing about your problem. Make sure to [edit] your question to include all **relevant** content. Providing more information such as what equipment you are using will increase your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Can you show e.g. a screenshot of your forwarding configuration?

Comment: There is no such limit, beside sind bind port which must be unique. Show Your current configuration that does not work and/or tell exactly what You want to achieve (at least essentially).